# How is CSS used to trim area of mouse rollover?

Tags: css

I have some code from an existing CSS map, and the part below is confusing as I think it has to do with making the rollover area (california1) more defined than a simple BOX.

My question: how does one write this themselves, and why use em and not pixels?

Example code:

```
#california1 .s1{height:.3em;left:14em;top:12.7em;width:.2em} 
#california1 .s2{height:.5em;left:13.8em;top:12.6em;width:.2em} 
#california1 .s3{height:.7em;left:13.7em;top:12.5em;width:.1em} 
#california1 .s4{height:.8em;left:13.6em;top:12.4em;width:.1em} 
#california1 .s5{height:.9em;left:13.5em;top:12.3em;width:.1em} 
#california1 .s6{height:1em;left:13.4em;top:12.2em;width:.1em}
```

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your first question, writing this yourself would be fairly simple -- I am viewing this out of context of the HTML, but I am guessing that each of those ".s1, .s2, etc" divs are just "segments" of the map.

EMs are used verses pixels because that will scale better than pixels when resizing a window, or viewing the site on a phone browser, etc.

Comment: Thank you. What software would be used to map out these units?

Answer (score 0):

`em` is relative to the `font-size` property. `1em` equals current element `font-size`.

If you are working on a static image, try increasing your browser's text-size and see that your segments will grow, not fitting in the map anymore.

You're saying you want it more defined, I hope you're using `map` and `area` [HTML elements](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) to define the clickable parts. Use area coordinates with `poly`shape to best define each part of California:

```
<map name="california">
    <area shape="poly" coords="x1,y1,x2,y2,... xn,yn" href="s1.html" alt="segment 1">
    <area shape="poly" coords="..." href="s2.html" alt="segment 2">
    ...
    <area shape="poly" coords="..." href="sn.html" alt="segment n">
</map>
```

Then assign it to your image with `usemap`:

```
<image usemap="#california" ... />
```

[Here](http://www.heartchildren.org.nz/test.html) you have an example.

I don't know if its too obvious, I just hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I am using CSS mapping similar to winstonwolf.pl/css,europe.html I have everything else coded but am lost as to define/measure the EMs for the shape definitions.

Comment: Don't use em for the shapes in static images, use pixels. With Dreamweaver it's very easy to define map areas, but for what you're trying, you have to calculate it by yourself